# What is the meaning of the metric “it/s” when training or evaluating models in Rasa?

Tags: machine-learning, chatbot, metrics, rasa

I am currently comparing several NLU configurations in the Rasa framework.

I would like to know what the `it` in `it/s` as seen in the log while training or evaluating a configuration in Rasa means. Iterations maybe? What does that metric exactly tell us?

Example from a recent log (metric used at the end of the line):

```
2020-11-22 17:04:37 INFO rasa.nlu.test - Running model for predictions: 100%|██| 83/83 [00:00<00:00, 182.72it/s]
```

I could not find anything by googling and searching the forums.
I have also asked the same question in the rasa forums before, but there seems to be little to no activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it/s` is not a (Rasa or ML specific) metric, it is just the iterations/second performed by the system (here during the prediction phase).

As a general rule, you may want to keep in mind that nothing really *important* (and certainly not any metric) is expected to be reported through an `INFO` message in the logs; `it/s` is just such an informational indication and, as already said, not a metric.